# Image and text alignment, footer and text problems

Tags: javascript, html, css

I don't have a clue how to place an image with text near it and it would be responsive text and image.

As you can see from this example, footer is in a middle of image. So my main question would be how to put image and then text near it (both of them responsive) and after that I could write something below; for example, plain text or put footer (without fixed position). I am just a beginner please don't be mad.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet"
        href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZC..."
        crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="reduit.css">
    <title>Hello, world!</title>
</head>
<body>
    <header id="main-header">
        <h1>Welcome to the Reduit beach website</h1>
    </header>
    <div class="left-half">
    </div>
    <div class="right-half">
        <article>
            <p>The world is full of beaches, but they are not all alike. In Amazing Beaches, students will read about beautiful beaches that have special features, such as pink sand or a shore covered in smooth glass pebbles. Gorgeous photographs illustrate the information in the text, and simple world maps show the location of each highlighted beach. Each small section is only one page long, and the sentence complexity is adjusted for emergent readers.</p>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Read more</a>
        </article>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
        <p>Footer</p>
    </div>
    <footer class="mainfooter">
        <p>foo</p>
    </footer>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-smHYKdLADwkXOn1EmN1qk/HfnUcbVRZyYmZ4qpPea6sjB/pTJ0euyQp0Mk8ck+5T" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </body>
</html>


body {
    font-size:18px;
}
```

CSS

```
#main-header {
    background-color: coral;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 20px;
}
article {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    width: 100%;
    padding: 20px;
}
/* .footer {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: rgb(43, 40, 40);
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top:20px;
} */
#mainfooter {
    background: #333;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    padding:20px;
    margin-top:40px;

}
.left-half {
    background:url('https://cdn.newsapi.com.au/image/v1/9fdbf585d17c95f7a31ccacdb6466af9') no-repeat;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    width: 50%;
    height: 60%;;
    background-size:cover;


}
.right-half {
    background-color: coral;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    width: 50%;
    height: 60%;
    text-align: center;

  }
```

Comment: You are trying to use position to achieve your desire which is causing a lot of issue in your layout why not consider doing it with float property?

Comment: I noticed you had included bootstrap. Why not to make a use of container, row and col ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```css
body {
    font-size:18px;
}
#main-header {
    background-color: coral;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 20px;
}
article {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 20px;
}
/* .footer {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: rgb(43, 40, 40);
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top:20px;
} */
#mainfooter {
    background: #333;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    padding:20px;
    margin-top:40px;

}
.left-half {
    background:url('https://cdn.newsapi.com.au/image/v1/9fdbf585d17c95f7a31ccacdb6466af9') no-repeat;
    width: 50%;
    height: 60%;
    float: left;
    background-size:cover;


}
.right-half {
    background-color: coral;
    float: right;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 50%;
    height: 60%;
    text-align: center;

  }

@media(max-width:470px){
   .right-half{
     width: 100%;
   }
   .left-half {
     width: 100%;
     }

}
```

```html
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="reduit.css">
        <title>Hello, world!</title>
      </head>
      <body>

            <header id="main-header">


                <h1>Welcome to the Reduit beach website</h1>

            </header>
            <div style="display: block;">

            <div class="left-half">


                </div>
                <div class="right-half">
                  <article>
                    <p>The world is full of beaches, but they are not all alike. In Amazing Beaches, students will read about beautiful beaches that have special features, such as pink sand or a shore covered in smooth glass pebbles. Gorgeous photographs illustrate the information in the text, and simple world maps show the location of each highlighted beach. Each small section is only one page long, and the sentence complexity is adjusted for emergent readers.</p>

                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Read more</a>
                  </article>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div style="clear: both"></div>

                <footer class="mainfooter" style="padding: 200px;">
                    <p>foo</p>
                </footer>


        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-smHYKdLADwkXOn1EmN1qk/HfnUcbVRZyYmZ4qpPea6sjB/pTJ0euyQp0Mk8ck+5T" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this for footer.

```
<div class="footer">
 <p>Footer</p>
</div>
```

and this CSS

```
.footer {

    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: red;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;

}
```